# Which unit is `distance` returning in this SQL query

Tags: mysql, haversine

I'm messing with some latitude/longitude related code in the Google Maps API which provides me with the following SQL statement

```
SELECT id, (
  3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) *
  cos( radians( lat ) ) *
  cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) +
  sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) )
AS distance
FROM marker
HAVING distance < 25
ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

Link to Google Maps example here: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3

However the distance returned is over 7,000, while I know that all of my entries in the database are within 50 miles of each other. I've verified this using http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html which also goes over the Haversine formula.

So I'm curious as to what I'm doing wrong with the provided query, which returns:

> (IMAGE)
>   http://gyazo.com/ece247747616c5a412edd40c82c4b0ce -- (Failed to upload image, format not accepted???).

All points are compared from

```
long: 39.410870
lat:  -107.102180
```

Here's the full query:

```
SELECT id,`user_long`,`user_lat`,
( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(39.410870) ) * cos( radians( `user_lat` ) ) * cos( radians( `user_long` ) - radians(-107.102180) ) + sin( radians(39.410870) ) * sin( radians( `user_lat` ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM `accounts`
ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20
```

As you can see in the results, it's really strange, because even when compared to itself, the distance is > 7000.

```
ID:    1
LONG: 39.410870
LAT:  -107.102180
DIST: 7923.067131806453
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Units is in miles.

It looks like you've got latitude and longitude reversed/swapped.

Valid range for latitude is only -90 to +90, it can't be -107  (degrees).

If you mean to specify a location in Colorado west of Denver, halfway to Grand Junction, swap the values for latitude and longitude.

The "great circle calculation" looks correct, it's going to return miles, since you are multiplying by 3959. (You'd need to replace that constant with a different one to get distance units other than miles.)

It looks like you've got the fixed latitude and longitude correctly place in the expression... I suspect it's the values in `user_lat` and `user_lng` that are swapped/reversed.

Comment: Yes, @spencer7593 is correct. See my SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b6ec9/1/0